# ReferenceError: ace is not defined

Tags: reactjs, react-ace

I'm new to ace and trying to build an Editor with react-ace.

Here is what I did:

1. `npm install react-ace ace-builds`
2. I added the following code to my App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import AceEditor from "react-ace";

import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-java";
import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/theme-github";

function onChange(newValue) {
  console.log("change", newValue);
}

// Render editor
render(
  <AceEditor
    mode="java"
    theme="github"
    onChange={onChange}
    name="UNIQUE_ID_OF_DIV"
    editorProps={{ $blockScrolling: true }}
  />,
  document.getElementById("example")
);
```

However my browser shows this error: ReferenceError: ace is not defined
[image]

Here is my package.json:
[image]

Can you help me please. Thank you!

Comment: It works [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-kowalevski-ocv62?file=/src/App.js) without a problem

Comment: I'll test it tonight and let you know!

Comment: same problem I'm running it on windows 10 I really don't understand why

Answer (score 6):

Add this code

```
import 'ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace';
```

To learn more, see our https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace/issues/1233

Answer (score 0):

There is no DOM element with `example` id. You are using create-react-app so you need to replace line:

```
document.getElementById("example")
```

to

```
document.getElementById("root")
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, in App.js don't need to use again render function, because already use in index.js component. For example, your code will look like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import AceEditor from "react-ace";
import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-java";
import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/theme-github";

const App = () => {

    const onChange = (newValue) => {
        console.log("change", newValue);
      }

    return (
        <AceEditor
            mode="java"
            theme="github"
            onChange={onChange}
            name="UNIQUE_ID_OF_DIV"
            editorProps={{ $blockScrolling: true }}
        />
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I still have the same problem

Answer (score -2):

make sure you are downloading ace-master, here is the link: https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds.

Comment: Can you provide more detail on how to use `ace-master` to solve the issue?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32106840)

Comment: Ther problem occurs when you add the themes, there is no way downloading another package gonna solve this